# Layered images as framebuffer with high number of layers

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to use a layered image (a 3D texture with 10-1000 z resolution) as the texture for a framebuffer.
I set the texture for the framebuffer via:

```
glGenTextures(1, &textureName);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, textureName);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 1, GL_R32F, width, height, depth);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, textureName, 0);
```

Then I create geometry for the layers in a geometry shader

```
void main() {
  for (int layer = 0; layer < textureDepth; ++layer) {
    gl_Layer = layer;
    //generate and emit vertices
    EndPrimitive();
  }
}
```

For small texture depth (e.g. 10) this seems to work but for bigger numbers the result seems to be wrong. There are many places where things could go wrong, so I wanted to make sure that this is working.

- Am I setting things up right?
- Are there limits to the number of layers that I have to query (`glGetInteger`)?
- Do you have any experience with the performace of highly layered images as framebuffers?

Note that my main problem is the lack of information on this topic.
The [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images) is very short and the part on non cube map layered images even shorter. I would be happy about any tutorial that covers this topic (not the cube map problem).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of limitations you can be hitting in this situation, but the one that comes to my mind first is `gl_MaxGeometryOutputVertices`. OpenGL implementations can restrict you to as few as 256 vertices output in a single geometry shader invocation. You can split your geometry shader into multiple invocations if you are hitting this limitation. In fact, for heavily layered rendering you should be using GS invocation anyway.

If you update your question with more details, particularly your full geometry shader, I can give you a more detailed answer. Including how to setup GS invocations if you are not already familiar with this.

Comment: I'd really like some guidance on how to set the number of invocations on the CPU side. The only way I found to set this number is via a layout specifier in the code, which is quite ugly if you want to adapt to the current platform's limit. However, I believe this should be a separate question.

Comment: @Nobody: Yeah, when you start doing things on the fringes of hardware capabilities you wind up having to come up with really elaborate schemes. You will probably have to templatize your geometry shader; generate a few lines of the shader text at run-time before compilation based on hardware / implementation capabilities. This is approaching the level of sophistication of dynamic material systems... if you do not want to bother with all that, you could always assume an implementation supports 256 vertices per-invocation and 32 invocations total and schedule your layer batches around this.

Comment: Okay for now I will use the lower limit. Could you please elaborate on the actual question: Is the outline given in my question the right way to do layered rendering? Unfortunately I cannot give much more information as I am not sure if I am allowed to give away code.